# Failing ajax requests, probably due to something called CORS?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors

I have a basic ajax request that retrieves a menu and puts it on a web page.

Here is the code

```
//display the menu
$.post(server+"quizz/phpScripts/retrieveMenu.php", {}, function(data){
    $("nav, #lowerMenu").html(data);
});
```

In my original files, 'server' was 'localhost', but when I hosted the site and tried to open the page, I get this error in the console.

Using firefox

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://edwaze.com/quizz/phpScripts/retrieveMenu.php. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

Using Safari

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://edwaze.com/quizz/phpScripts/retrieveMenu.php. Origin http://www.edwaze.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Using Chrome

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://edwaze.com/quizz/phpScripts/retrieveMenu.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://edwaze.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I've read quite a bit on this, but I haven't found a solution yet. Please help. And go easy with the terminologies please, i'm a bit new to ajax :)

Thanks.

Comment: Please, read more about CORS here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Have you made any cross domain request? You have hosted to `https` secured server.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi ! Yes its a https secured server, does this make this simpler or harder for me?

Comment: @VincentHokie Is the resource you are trying to download using AJAX hosted on the same server as the page that makes the request?

Comment: Do you have control over that remote domain? The headers to allow your site script access must be set there – you can not set them on your end.

Comment: If you are accessing your website without HTTPS then do your AJAX call without HTTPS.

Comment: @spender , yes sir..same server

Comment: @CBroe yes, I do, please provide the headers and where to place them please.

Comment: @VincentHokie Then CORS is not relevant to your problem and you'd be best to follow the advice of of [Jai's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34677044/14357) by using root relative URLs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are not making any cross domain requests it would be better to use root relative urls:

```
$.post("/quizz/phpScripts/retrieveMenu.php"
```

the leading `/` represents the root of the application.

---

That issue arises when you have `http/https` protocols added in the url and urls are hosted on webserver not on localhost.

Comment: unfortunately, this didn't work guys..the errors are gone, but i still don't get the menu displaying

Comment: @VincentHokie could you plz tell us what do you see in the network tab of your browser inspector tool? Do you see any request logged?

Comment: Sorry @Jai is appears your solution did work, my queries are being executed on the server end, my problem appears to now be the php version. So thank you. Do you happen to know where php version 5.4 native supports mysqli functions?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this URL. It will help you to resolve your query.

[CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276220/cors-header-access-control-allow-origin-missing)

As per the errors, it seems that you need to set Cross Origin so that you can access data from another domain.

Comment: That's fantastic. HOW, do i do this?

Comment: This answer is not relevant because OP is not actually trying to make a cross-origin request.