# The CORS Header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is missing

Tags: javascript, http, cors

I'm trying to use webUntis'([docs](https://api.webuntis.dk/api/docs)) API for a school project. For now I'm just trying to establish any kind of connection to the API.

```
var result;
const url = 'https://api.webuntis.dk/api/status';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET',url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET');
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-API-KEY', '/*API KEY*/');
xhr.send();


xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        result = xhr.responseType;
        console.log(result);
    }
};
```

This code produces the following error message:

> Cross-Origin request blocked: The same origin policy prohibits the
>   reading of the external resource at https://api.webuntis.dk/api/status
>   (Reason: CORS Header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is missing).

How may this problem be solved? Perhaps my API key is wrong?

Disclaimer: The error message was translated from German.

Comment: Looks pretty much that you are not requesting your own server, instead, directly to `https://api.webuntis.dk/api/status` you should create a route, request your local server and then make the request server to server

Comment: First of all, the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` should be on the requested file header, not in your request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276220/cors-header-access-control-allow-origin-missing)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are making a request to another site, in this case the API at `api.webuntis.dk`. This type of request is called a "Cross Origin Request"

For such requests to work in JavaScript, **the server on their end needs to allow them**.

This is done by their server sending special CORS headers, the most basic one being the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header.

I guess the API provider has not foreseen or planned for this API to be used from a frontend (e.g. JavaScript in the browser), so you would have to work around this.

One way is to set up your own server and have the JavaScript code make a request to your server and your server then making a request to the API, as server side code is not bound to CORS headers.

Alternatively, to try things out, you can prefix the URL with `https://cors.io` like this:

```
const url = 'https://cors.io/?https://api.webuntis.dk/api/status';
```

Comment: Unfortunately cors.io is no more available. Is there any alternative site?

Comment: There's https://corsproxy.github.io/ but remember: That is only for testing / development purposes, not for production use!

For production use, either proxy it through your own server or setup your own CORS proxy.

Answer (score 8):

**What is CORS ?**

from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) :

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses
>   additional HTTP headers to let a user agent gain permission to access
>   selected resources from a server on a different origin (domain) than
>   the site currently in use. A user agent makes a cross-origin HTTP
>   request when it requests a resource from a different domain, protocol,
>   or port than the one from which the current document originated.

**SOLUTION**

You need to settings the CORS permission in your server. (`https://api.webuntis.dk/api/status`)

Setting Example :

1. PHP

   `<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`
2. Rails

   `#in config/application.rb
   config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
      'Access-Control-Request-Method' => %w{GET POST OPTIONS}.join(",")
   }`

note: Change * to specific URL that you want to allow CORS. '*' is highly discouraged, unless you are providing a public API that is intended to be accessed by any consumer out there.

Comment: You should provide attribution for the first section of the answer. That's [copied from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Answer (score 2):

It basically means that this API is not configured to be called from another web page. Cross-Origin refers to making an HTTP request from one domain (origin) to another. This API is meant to be used from a server application. If you need to call it from a web page, you'll need to create a simple proxy server that your web page can call which will make the request to webUntis.

Answer (score 0):

Sending Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the server solves nothing. Server has to send Access-Control-Allow-Origin set to * to your browser to allow ajax requests to run.