# How to fix 'TypeError: name.toUpperCase is not a function' in axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, dbpedia

I want to get data from dbpedia endpoint, with axios in vue js.

I use `axios.get` to get data from dbpedia, and i got and error in console say :

> TypeError: name.toUpperCase is not a function

How can i fix it?

```
created(){
    this.fetch();
  },
  methods: {
    fetch(){
      axios
      .get('http://id.dbpedia.org/sparql?query=SELECT+DISTINCT+?concept+WHERE+{+?s+a+?concept+}+LIMIT+50', {
        headers: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'
      }).then(response => {
        /* eslint-disable */
        console.log('SUCCESS');
        console.log(response);
      }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      })
    }
  },
```

Comment: Please include the code where you are using `name.toUpperCase`. My first guess is you didn't call `toUpperCase()` as a string method, because you left off the parentheses.

Comment: which line that i should include ```name.toUpperCase``` ?

Comment: No, I'm saying to edit in the code where you are currently using it in your question, so we can look at how you're using it.

Comment: Hey, your error seems to come from somewhere else. Somewhere you use the toUpperCase method.

Comment: @LenJoseph I'm not using any name.toUpperCase method. This is just empty template.

Comment: Can you please tell us from which file the error seems to come ? You have the info inside the devtools

Comment: I check in console, the error come from file name normalizeHeaderName.js?c8af:7 this file come from  axios/lib/helpers/normalizeHeaderName.js?c8af:7.

Comment: Without seeing the code and knowing what `name` is or where it was used, all I can say is 1 of 3 scenarios is probably happening:

1) name is not of type `String`, and this cannot take a string method.
2) There is an attempt at string mutation, (e.g., `let string = a; let string = string.toUpperCase()`. This would fail because Strings are immutable, and the new variable requires a different variable name.
3) `toUpperCase` was used without parens.

Comment: `'use strict';

var utils = require('../utils');

module.exports = function normalizeHeaderName(headers, normalizedName) {
  utils.forEach(headers, function processHeader(value, name) {
    if (name !== normalizedName && name.toUpperCase() === normalizedName.toUpperCase()) {
      headers[normalizedName] = value;
      delete headers[name];
    }
  });
};` That is the code in that file i mention before. That file located in webpack.

Comment: I see, look at the answer in this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49948400/react-axios-get-not-working-log-out-name-touppercase-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change your Axios request to this:

```
methods: {
async fetch () {
await axios.get('https://cors.io/?http://id.dbpedia.org/sparql?query=SELECT+DISTINCT+?concept+WHERE+{+?s+a+?concept+}+LIMIT+50', {
            headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': *},
             mode: 'cors',
          }).then(response => {
            /* eslint-disable */
            console.log('SUCCESS');
            console.log(response.data);
          }).catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
          }
     }
}
```

Five changes:

1) Made Axios `headers` an object (note where the quotation marks are)

2) `console.log(response.data)`

3) Added `mode: 'cors'`

4) Added `cors` prefix to URL, since you're retrieving data from a third-party domain outside your hosting environment

5) Wrapped your `fetch` function in `async` `await`, since axios is a promise-based library.

Comment: Hey @LenJoseph that code that u mention above that's work fine, but it get data from dari uri is very slow. How can i improve that ?

Comment: What do you mean by slow? How long does it take?

Comment: When i go that page that contain that code, it get data from uri it's slow, about 6 - 8 second

Comment: There are many things that could slow it down. If they have high traffic or other server issues, that could slow the response. If your local bandwidth is low, that will also be a factor. I'm not familiar with this API, but I see you've limited the response to 50 items, which should be relatively fast from a data volume perspective. Does your console log show any errors when you make the request?

Comment: Yea, in my console it takea few second to get the data, sometime i get error : **from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

Comment: I call this code from method in vue, when i already get the data the console still running to get data, and it can't stop

Comment: Please see edit to my answer. I added `async` and `await` for your axios getter. This will return a promise for your API call.

Answer (score 3):

Similar issue was face by me in my learning phase and solved by making the headers as object instead of string :

```
headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true }
```

Comment: If i use tha code i got a error  :  **from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

Answer (score -1):

for me it was camel case mistake in toUpperCase in js make sure u see for it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).