# Vue/MySQL Database not appearing online, but is locally?

Tags: mysql, vue.js, express, server

Currently, when I'm running my application locally, everything works just fine as intended. However, when I push everything to the Heroku server, the page contents that are connected to the MySQL Database do not show up without any CORS errors or any errors when doing a fetch call in Chrome Dev Tools. The Page itself loads, but it is just blank after a header.

I'm connected to ClearDB and the backend is deployed. I can view all the routes I would like to get with Axios, just not as intended on Heroku. Here is one API call I have in a Vue Component I have setup

```
    getTeams() {
      const headers = [{ "Content-Type": "application/json" }, { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://the-fame-of-honor.herokuapp.com" }];
      axios.get("https://fame-of-honor-server.herokuapp.com/api/teams", { headers })
        .then((response) => {
          this.teams = response.data;
          console.log("Teams", response.data);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log("error", e);
        });
    },
```

Here is the code for both backend and frontend if that helps.

[Server Code](https://github.com/brunojoey/fame-of-honor-server) (Node, Express, MySQL)

[Front End Code](https://github.com/brunojoey/fame-of-honor) (Vue)

Below is the fetch request I do to see if any errors happen, but the response is fulfilled but no data comes through there still. So it is very strange I think?

[image: 3]

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you *sure* you have migrated *content* to the deployed DB?  Shot in the dark as it wasn't clear if you were using a local db.  Regardless, what happens if you use curl locally?

Comment: When I do a local curl call, all the data returns as it should from the API route I tried. I am using a local DB and connecting that with ClearDB yeah! When I do check that deployed DB locally through Workbench, everything does show up.

Comment: Bother, I suppose I could have checked it myself.  It works this end too.

Comment: Added a component I have setup with Axios if that'll help at all in any future questions

Comment: The promise is *not* fulfilled---only the cors request is.

Comment: btw `{ "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://the-fame-of-honor.herokuapp.com" }` you don't set these on the *frontend*, but on the backend (you let the browser handle CORS, but it only sets origin).  Doubt that's the problem though

Comment: Okay deal. Then I just add a header for the promise? Or just include that for the error handling? Then hopefully it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the web inspector for the deployed app (not linking in case you don't want it linked) it doesn't even *try* to fetch the data: it stalls on an error `TypeError: r.toUpperCase is not a function`.  It's not even trying the fetch (any fetching errors are another matter).

Looking at the code the error being thrown (which may or may not be the overall problem) is likely down to the headers being passed as an array rather than a single object.  (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56460636/how-to-fix-typeerror-name-touppercase-is-not-a-function-in-axios) )  Specifically you should pass headers like this:

```js
  methods: {
    getTeams() {
      const headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" };
      axios.get("https://fame-of-honor-server.herokuapp.com/api/teams"), headers)
        .then((response) => {
          this.teams = response.data;
          console.log("Teams", response.data);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log("error", e);
        });
    },
  },
```

If you need multiple headers, just put them in the object.  Note that you *shouldn't* send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`: that's sent by the *backend* in response to an `Origin` header which the browser will add automatically.

With modern js you can also write it like this, which I personally think is easier to read:

```js
try {
  const { data } = await axios.get(url, headers);
  this.teams = data;
} catch(e) {
  console.error(e)
}
```

Comment: I did see this. The line it's referencing is the console log of the error so I am unsure about that overall.

Comment: because you catch the error and log it!  But if you take that out you can see it's happening elsewhere: error TypeError: name.toUpperCase is not a function
    at processHeader (normalizeHeaderName.js?c8af:7)

Comment: Hm hm hm okay. That might've just made me more confused as to why that happens

Comment: updated, but vue is *not* playing ball this end tonight so I'm leaving it for now

Comment: That was the issue it seems having the headers be an array! Thank you!

Comment: Oh good! Feel free to accept if it works now:)

Comment: Was rather brief last night, sorry.  Also problem was my editing your `Team.vue` not `Teams.vue`.  I have updated this answer so it's a decent reference in the future.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it!