# API and Vue js in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I'm totally new to the `laravel` and `vue.js` frameworks. For a school project we have to create an app that uses `laravel` for the back-end and `vue.js` for the front-end. So I created an API to use it afterwards in my `vue.Js`.

But the problem is that when I want to get the data in my Vue.JS it tells me this:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/lsapp/public/api/posts. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

I have been struggling since 2 days on it and now, I'm totally lost, I don't know what to do or what goes wrong.. I tried my API into postman and it works perfectly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276220/cors-header-access-control-allow-origin-missing)

Comment: are you running the vue script from localhost also? Are you using Apache?

Comment: yes! i am using wamp @user1491032

Comment: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors