# Why does my API call work in Chrome but not in my code?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to call the Binance API to get the LTC price in BTC and I tested the link on my browser "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/price?symbol=LTCBTC" How do i get the JSON file from that link into my JavaScript file?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/price?symbol=LTCBTC';

$.ajax( {
    url: url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
            console.log(data); //returns nothing
        }
});

})
```

Comment: in my browser `jsonp` complains `blocked due to MIME type (“application/json”) mismatch`, and `json` complains `CORS`

Comment: are you using an api key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in other answer, there is CORS issue. So you can try with proxyURL from client side as below,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/price?symbol=LTCBTC';

const proxyURL = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
$.getJSON(proxyURL + url, function(playerData) {
  console.log(playerData);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The request to https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/price?symbol=LTCBTC provides json data this uses CORS policy

> {"symbol":"LTCBTC","price":"0.01520100"}

JSONP would look like

> myCallback({"symbol":"LTCBTC","price":"0.01520100"})

This looks like and works like a Javascript / PHP function.

The URL for a jsonp includes a callback in the URL ...  https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/price?symbol=LTCBTC&callback=myCallback

But is not supported on this site

> {"code":-1101,"msg":"Too many parameters; expected '1' and received
>   '2'."}

---

It might be openable with php on your site? I can not test from the system I'm on  I don't have socket transport "ssl" setup on my tablet to test.

Yes it works from a PHP wrapper.

```
myJSONP(<?php echo file_get_contents('https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/price?symbol=LTCBTC');?>);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check on console after change dataType: 'jsonp' to dataType: 'json', you will get the following as your code and their script not on same host and they need to enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin to access from other domain. You may use cur if you use php.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/price?symbol=LTCBTC. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276220/cors-header-access-control-allow-origin-missing here is post about that.

Answer (score 0):

While performing the request from your browser or postman or fiddler you will get the result

But while performing a request from the application you will be failed with error message

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/price?symbol=LTCBTC' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The issue has to be fixed from your server side end.

Please refer

[Cors understanding](https://crunchify.com/how-to-fix-access-control-allow-origin-issue-for-your-https-enabled-wordpress-site-and-maxcdn/)

Also, find the solution to the problem if you're using C# .Net as your backend

[Solution for cors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)