# Download blob file attachment from discord using rest api

Tags: javascript, discord, fetch

I have a discord message that have an attachment. This attachment is a blob file, that have html code inside. I need to get a raw response text, because it have html code inside. When I try to fetch it, it says "Access-Control-Allow-Origin Missing Header" with CORS, but in Postman I have what I need. How to get a html text from url that download blob file?

```js
fetch("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/924478995830013995/1026201687628718112/blob")
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

*Link is real, so you can download this blob file and add a `.html` file extension, also you can test that Postman get a html code well.*

Comment: The server you’re attempting to call is configured with CORS headers to disallow cross-domain requests from end users’ browsers. Unless you control the server, you won’t be able to access this URL from in-browser JavaScript without something like an intermediary proxy.

Comment: Please research your inquiry before posting in accordance with [ask]. Duplicate of [CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276220/cors-header-access-control-allow-origin-missing)

Answer (score -1):

"Access-Control-Allow-Origin Missing Header" with CORS means you have to provide the header key mode which will be **cors** by default. Here you have to provide the mode as **no-cors** to support the cross-origin requests.

Secondly, You have to return the response as **response.blob()** to download the file attachement.

Comment: This solution does not satisfy the requirements of the OP. MDN explicitly mentions that `no-cors` will disallow JavaScript from accessing any properties of the resulting `Response`. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode#value)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).