# React can't fetch JSON from a public endpoint

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm trying to use it to fetch data from a publicly available endpoint that exposes a simple JSON object. I can see the data by hitting this endpoint via my browser, via [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info), etc. But React keeps returning `"Type Error: failed to fetch"`. What am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://phmwu2mdn6.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev/conferences/GetDigital2023/Lectures"
      );
      const parsed = await response.json();
      setData(parsed);
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I need to see the JSON data, not the error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276220/cors-header-access-control-allow-origin-missing)

Comment: Do you have any errors printed on your console while running the application?  if so please share them here.