# CORS Issue with Angular and ASP.NET Core gRPC Service: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Missing

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, cors, grpc

I am working on an Angular project where I am trying to consume a gRPC service hosted on an ASP.NET Core server. However, when making requests from my Angular app, I encounter the following CORS-related error messages:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://server-address/Service/GetAll. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 404.

my address is `localhost:4200` .

On the client side, I am using `@ngx-grpc` to make the gRPC calls. Here's a snippet of my Angular component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Empty } from '@ngx-grpc/well-known-types';
import { TourServiceClient } from 'proto/tour.pbsc';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular-grpc';
  public tours: any[] = [];

  constructor(private client: TourServiceClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const responseStream = this.client.getAll(new Empty());
    console.log(responseStream)
    responseStream.subscribe((data:any)=>{
      console.log(data)
    })
  }
}
```

**what the problem ? how can i solve that ?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276220/cors-header-access-control-allow-origin-missing)

Comment: Try to add [CORS Header](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server) to api

Comment: @XinranShen Im using the GRPC