# I'm getting a 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header' error when trying to fetch data from the Clash Royale API. Any suggestions?

Tags: json, cors

```
var token = my_token;

var headers = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
};

function getClashRoyalePlayerInfo() {
  fetch("https://api.clashroyale.com/v1/players/%23R09228V", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: headers,
  })
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    });
}

getClashRoyalePlayerInfo();
```

I'm encountering a 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header error while fetching data from the Clash Royale API. Any suggestions?

Documentation of the Clash Royale API: [HERE](https://developer.clashroyale.com/#/getting-started)

I'm new to working with APIs, so any guidance or explanations would be greatly appreciated. :)

```
{
clan    PlayerClan{...}
legacyTrophyRoadHighScore   integer
currentDeckSupportCards PlayerItemLevelList[...]
arena   Arena{...}
role    string
Enum:
Array [ 5 ]
wins    integer
losses  integer
totalDonations  integer
leagueStatistics    PlayerLeagueStatistics{...}
cards   PlayerItemLevelList[...]
supportCards    PlayerItemLevelList[...]
currentFavouriteCard    Item{...}
badges  PlayerAchievementBadgeList[...]
currentDeck PlayerItemLevelList[...]
tag string
name    string
expLevel    integer
trophies    integer
bestTrophies    integer
donations   integer
donationsReceived   integer
achievements    PlayerAchievementProgressList[...]
battleCount integer
threeCrownWins  integer
challengeCardsWon   integer
challengeMaxWins    integer
tournamentCardsWon  integer
tournamentBattleCount   integer
warDayWins  integer
clanCardsCollected  integer
starPoints  integer
expPoints   integer
totalExpPoints  integer
currentPathOfLegendSeasonResult PathOfLegendSeasonResult{...}
lastPathOfLegendSeasonResult    PathOfLegendSeasonResult{...}
bestPathOfLegendSeasonResult    PathOfLegendSeasonResult{...}
}
```

This is the kind of output that I was expecting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276220/cors-header-access-control-allow-origin-missing). You might wanna check out the [docs on MDN for CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: Thank you for your response; the documentations that you mentioned lacks information about CORS, particularly in the context of JavaScript. :/

Comment: My second link is literaly THE documentation for CORS. However, there are plenty of videos and tutorials on this in the internet if you search for CORS, if you are not happy with this one. This is one of the most common issues faced in web development.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I may have overlooked it, but I'll revisit the second link for CORS documentation, thank you.